rplidar 2d to 3d point cloud
Hello I hope you guys can help me to distinguish this problem of mine. Is IMU is needed to attain the 3d Point cloud using my 2d rplidar? Or is it just the Servo Motor itself. How can I configure it on my Ubuntu 20.04?

If Lidar is stationary and you are taking something like a snapshot, imu is not required. You can use the angle of the servo motor for reconstruction. You can even move the lidar frame and note the exact movements manually for the reconstruction of data. But if lidar is mounted on the robot (mobile object), It is desirable to have an imu or another kind of sensor to map the environment and get better results. Often, people combine imu and odometer with lidar for mapping.
